# Can a 'linked'-file be renamed programatically via an Extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I've written an Extension that, among many other things, renames files based on the Types they contain.

This works fine for files in the directory-tree under the csproj-file -- I find the ProjectItem entry for the file and change its name.

For 'linked'-files (those not in the directory-tree) I can rename the file (via File.Move()) but haven't found a way to programatically modify the csproj-file (after the rename the csproj-file has to be modified manually).

If this is something that can be done I'd appreciate a pointer to the docs showing how to implement the functionality.

Comment: Does [Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.buildengine?view=netframework-4.8) Namespace help?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The classes in that namespace are deprecated - replaced by Microsoft.Build.Construction - which I'll check out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution for me was to modify the csproj-file.

1. Open, read whole file, close.
2. Verify that file I want to rename (e.g. xxx.cs) only occurs in 1 directory
   (if it occurs in multiple directories the change has to be done manually.)
3. Make change
4. Open, write whole file, close

- For an SDK project the change is applied immediately.
- For a non-SDK project the change is applied after responding to the prompt that the csproj-file has been modified.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, and please don't forget to [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this is a good reference.